# How to install cetoys on Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 64

Tags: rpm, alien

I am trying to install [cetoys](http://cetoys.sourceforge.net/). The [main Source Forge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cetoys/) provides a .src.rpm file. I downloaded it and ran:

`sudo alien -i cetoys-0-r4.src.rpm`

It produced the following output:

```
(Reading database ... 209118 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack cetoys_0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cetoys (0-1) over (0-1) ...
Setting up cetoys (0-1) ...
```

I thought maybe it was installed so I tried running `rapi help`. Which just informed me rapi command not found. I have never used alien before, and I don't really know what I am doing. Where would it have installed cetoys?

Comment: Does `dpkg --listfiles cetoys` produce any output?

Comment: Yes:`/.
/cetoys.tar.gz
/cetoys.spec
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/cetoys
/usr/share/doc/cetoys/copyright
/usr/share/doc/cetoys/changelog.Debian.gz`

Comment: Just noticed it's a .src file. That's source code, not executables. http://cetoys.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html has instructions for building it. I'd guess that `/cetoys.tar.gz` is the tarball of the source.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I though alien would get at the source and build it and install it, but I guess that was wishful thinking. Rats...

Answer (score 1):

---

When you follow your link http://sourceforge.net/projects/cetoys/ >> Browse all files >> cetoys/r4/ ,,, you will find "cetoys-0-r4.x86_64.rpm"
http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/cetoys/cetoys/r4/cetoys-0-r4.x86_64.rpm 
Which is a binary package : `$ sudo alien cetoys-0-r4.x86_64.rpm`

You will get : cetoys_0-1_amd64.deb ,,, which can be installed, and can run when a couple of special dependencies are installed beforehand.

1) libhal1_0.5.14-8_amd64.deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/hal/libhal1_0.5.14-8_amd64.deb

2) libsynce0_0.15-1.1_amd64.deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libs/libsynce/libsynce0_0.15-1.1_amd64.deb

Both are Ubuntu 12.04 packages. 'libsynce0' is a "Helper library to sync Windows Mobile devices".

"cetoys_0-1_amd64.deb" provides /usr/bin/{ cidb, rapi }.

---

Comment: It's either still not installed correctly, or there is something I need to do to "initialize" cetoys. When I run `rapi ls "/Documents and Settings"` I get `Error 1 (package not initialized properly). System error 1 (Incorrect function.).`